# Closed form expression for a summation over positive integers

Tags: combinatorics, summation, partial-fractions

we have the summation :
$$\underset{n\neq m}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\frac{n^{j-1}}{\left(n-m\right)^{j+1}}$$
where  $j,m$ are positive integers . By partial fraction expansion, we have:
$$\underset{n\neq m}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\frac{n^{j-1}}{\left(n-m\right)^{j+1}}=\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{i}\underset{n\neq m}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\frac{m^{j-1-i}}{(n-m)^{j-i+1}}$$
We use the series expansion of the [polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) to write the rightmost summation in terms of the limit:
$$\underset{n\neq m}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\frac{1}{(n-m)^{j-i+1}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow m}(-1)^{j-i+1}\frac{\psi^{(j-i)}(1-z)}{(j-i)!}-\frac{1}{(m-z)^{j-i+1}}$$
 or, in terms of the [Hurwitz Zeta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html):
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow m}\zeta(j-i+1,1-z)-\frac{1}{(m-z)^{j-i+1}}$$
1)Is there a closed form for limit!?

2)Is there another way we can write our summation in closed form !?

Comment: The expression is easily written as a finite sum through reindexing and use of the $\zeta$ function. But is that not "closed-form" enough? $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{j} \binom{j-1}{k-1}m^{k}\zeta(k+1)$

Comment: that's beautiful, can you elaborate, how did you arrive at this expression !?

Comment: Minor error in that expression: see my answer for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1,n\neq m}^\infty\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}} &=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}}+\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}}\\
\\&\phantom{=}\text{This is how I re-index; literally replace every $n$.} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}}+\sum_{n+m=m+1}^{n+m=\infty}\frac{(n+m)^{j-1}}{((n+m)-m)^{j+1}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+m)^{j-1}}{n^{j+1}}\\
\\&\phantom{=}\text{Use the Binomial Theorem.} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{j+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{k}n^{j-1-k}m^k\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{k}n^{-2-k}m^k\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}}+\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{k}m^k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2-k}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}}+\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{k}m^k\zeta(k+2)\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: The version in my comment is in error. Where you see $m^{k}$, you should see $m^{k-1}$. Then both are literally equal after a substitution $k\to k-1$.

Comment: For $m=1$, $j=2$, this yields $\zeta(2)+\zeta(3)$. With $\zeta(3)$ so mysterious, it feels unlikely that there exists some one-term expression for your sum unless you just define something new: $M(m,j)$.

Comment: actually, this summation came out while trying to evaluate : $$\frac{d^{j}}{ds^{j}}\left(\gamma+\psi\left(\frac{s-1}{s}\right)+\frac{1}{m(ms-1)}\right)$$ at $$s=\frac{1}{m}$$

Comment: in particular :$$\frac{1}{j!}\frac{d^{j}}{ds^{j}}\left(\gamma+\psi\left(\frac{s-1}{s}\right)+\frac{1}{m(ms-1)}\right)=(-m)^{j+1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n^{j-1}}{(n-m)^{j+1}}+\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{k}m^k\zeta(k+2)\right)$$